# Boot terminal not working properly

Tags: boot

I am having problems with my ubuntu 12.04, it hangs at “checking battery state”, but what is wierd is that when that stage is reached, I open up the terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, and can't run anything.

- sudo is not installed,
- apt-get is not installed,
- cant login to superuser,
- authentication fails

Answer (score 0):

It seems to get that far in posting tasks, but it is usually not related to battery state. Often it is video related, but could need other boot parameters.

You should first try nomodeset as a boot parameter at grub menu. Works for most video issues, but depending on video card/chip other setting or other devices may need different settings or both nomodeset & other settings.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

On first boot after install, press e on getting the GRUB bootloader menu. 
Hold shift from BIOS boot to get menu if only one system installed.
Using arrow keys navigate to and delete quiet and splash and type the word nomodeset in their place